# How to autoload files in folder under rails app's root

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, autoloader

I am trying to have files under `myapplication/somefolder`. Google and Stackoverflow say I should add this:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/somefolder)
```

in my `config/application.rb`, so I did.

But the files don't get loaded.

I tried namig `somefolder/myclass.rb` both `class Myclass` and `class Somefolder::Myclass` but still no luck.

I can see that the dir was found in `Rails.application.config.autoload_paths` in console does indeed include my `/path/to/myapplication/somefolder` directory, so that should be okay.

All the other questions around this topic use `theapp/app/somefolder` or `theapp/lib/somefolder` but not `theapp/somefolder` so maybe thats where it gets rotten.

So I tried referencing the class with `::Somefolder::MyClass` but not even that helped.

I am using Rails 3.2.1

Comment: More research shows that `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths` didn't contain my `somefolder` path at runtime. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just ran into this myself today and decided to dive deep.

The reason you don't see in `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths` the paths you're adding to `config.autoload_paths` in `config/application.rb` is that they aren't copied over until the application is initialized.  See `rails/engine.rb` in the `railties` gem:

```
module Rails
  class Engine < Railtie
    …

    # Set the paths from which Rails will automatically load source files,
    # and the load_once paths.
    #
    # This needs to be an initializer, since it needs to run once
    # per engine and get the engine as a block parameter
    initializer :set_autoload_paths, :before => :bootstrap_hook do |app|
      ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths.unshift(*_all_autoload_paths)
      ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_once_paths.unshift(*_all_autoload_once_paths)

      # Freeze so future modifications will fail rather than do nothing mysteriously
      config.autoload_paths.freeze
      config.eager_load_paths.freeze
      config.autoload_once_paths.freeze
    end

    …

    def _all_autoload_paths
      @_all_autoload_paths ||= (config.autoload_paths + config.eager_load_paths + config.autoload_once_paths).uniq
    end

    …
  end
end
```

Were you by any chance trying to invoke `MyClass` from within `config/application.rb` or, even earlier, from a script or module that requires `config/application.rb`?  If so, you'll have to explicitly require the file defining `MyClass`, e.g.:

```
require File.expand_path('../../somefolder/my_class',  __FILE__)
# now use MyClass
```

Answer (score 1):

The workaround is to go to `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths` directly.

```
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths << "#{config.root}/somefolder"
```

But I am still looking for the reason why config.autoload_paths didn't work so if you post an aswer to that, I'll accept it!

Comment: I have a same problem too :(. I'm using Rails 3.2.3.

Answer (score 1):

You should name `somefolder/my_class.rb` in order to autoload `MyClass`. You also should keep that `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/somefolder)` line in your `config/application.rb`.