# Rails services globally available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails API, I want to use the services globally without require them in the controllers.

Print off the "#{config.root}" shows "/Users/sorry/Projects/project_Api/Api_test"

Structure

`Api_test ---->     app ----->  services ------> services.rb`

In "config/application.rb" I have tried many things.

`config.autoload_paths += ["#{config.root}/app/services/sales_flow_service.rb"]`


`config.autoload_paths += ["#{config.root}/app/services"]`

with a different structure.

`Api_test ---->     app ----->  lib ------> services.rb`

and

`Api_test ---->     app ----->  lib ------> services ----> services.rb`


`config.autoload_paths += ["#{config.root}/app/lib"]`


`config.autoload_paths += ["#{config.root}/app/lib/services/services.rb"]`

For some reason it does not work. What am I missing?
Thanks in advance

Comment: what so you mean by not using in controllers ??

Comment: They are separately, but I call them from the controller. I need to 
require 'service.rb'
I do not want to, I need them to be available everywhere, do u know what I mean?

Comment: In recent versions of Rails, everything in `app` is autoloaded.  What version of Rails is this?

Comment: the version is Rails 4.2.6, I am afraid it does not load it for some reason Jim :\

Comment: strange that it isn't working, might be how you are calling the classes or code from services.rb?

Comment: maybe take at look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430097/how-to-autoload-files-in-folder-under-rails-apps-root

Comment: Agush, that was a really good post/information, thanks.